# 404 Not Found when accessing static HTML in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http-post, http-status-code-404

I've been trying to reference Spring's guides (which hasn't been too useful to the inexperienced me for completing this particular task in full) to create a simple toy example: Handle a form submission as a POST request and display the result.

**Update**: `ViewConfiguration` class added - see bottom of question for further information.

This is my project structure:

```
src
 |  main
 |   |  java
 |   |   |  controllers
 |   |   |   |  BasicController.java
 |   |   |   |  RestfulController.java
 |   |   |  Application.java
 |   |   |  ViewConfiguration.java
 |   |  resources
 |   |   |  static
 |   |   |   |  form.html
```

My code are as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}

@Controller
public class BasicController {
  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String greeting() {
    return "form";
  }
}

@RestController
public class RestfulController {
  @RequestMapping(value="/result", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public String parseForm(@RequestParam String name) {
    return name;
  }
}

@Configuration
public class ViewConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  @Bean
  public UrlBasedViewResolver urlBasedViewResolver() {
    UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new urlBasedViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/static");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setCache(false);
    return resolver;
  }
}
```

For `form.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="result" method="post">
      Name: <input type="text" name="name">
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I run the above in Eclipse as a Java Application, the URL `http://localhost:8080/` only yields a `HTTP 404 Not Found` error. I've tried all of the following return values for `greeting()` without success:

- form
- form.html
- /form
- /form.html
- /static/form
- /static/form.html
- /resources/static/form
- /resources/static/form.html

I have a pre-existing application that processes GET requests correctly when I submit a hard-coded URL. However, I need to use POST instead. As far as I know, this can't tested via a hard-coded URL - it must be done through a form submission. So far I have been unable to replicate the earlier success I had with the GET version.

**Update**: Following suggestions in the answers below, I added a view resolver but instead of using a third party one like Thyme, I created a basic, custom one as shown above.

At present, I've received an `IllegalArgumentException: Property 'viewClass' is required`

All the online tutorials I can find use `resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);` but since just about all of my views are static `.html` pages, I'm not sure I should be using `JstlView`. It is also clear from the above that I can't just leave it blank either.

What should I set `viewClass` as? Are there any other mistakes in my code at present? Ultimately, how do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out that the main issue is due to my project classpath (set in Eclipse as simply `/src/`) being different from that used in most online tutorials (`/src/main/`). So the final result is as follows:

```
src
 |  main
 |   |  java
 |   |   |  controllers
 |   |   |   |  BasicController.java
 |   |   |   |  RestfulController.java
 |   |   |  Application.java
 |  META-INF
 |   |  resources
 |   |   |  form.html

@Controller
public class BasicController {
  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String greeting() {
    return "form.html";
  }
}

@RestController
public class RestfulController {
  @PostMapping("/result")
  public String parseForm(@RequestParam String name) {
    return name;
  }
}
```

The `ViewConfiguration` class is unnecessary and is thus removed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified any additional `ViewResolver`, there's no one, that will check for views in `/src/resources/...`.
To do it you should specify a `ViewResolver`, or let `Spring Boot` to register it. To do this, you can simply include `Spring Boot Starter Thymeleaf` into your project. This starter has `ViewResolver` definition, that checks for views in resources dir.

Try also to add a view in /resources/templates/ dir.

Comment: Is Thymeleaf really necessary? I thought view resolvers are used to generate a webpage from a template? That's not what I want to do. I just want to display the static page `form.html` as-is. There's nothing to add. Also, in my actual project I only have access to whatever is native to the Spring or Spring Boot library in the local repository.

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: Thymeleaf is not necessary. It just creates a ViewResolver that you could also make yourself. Including Thymeleaf is not the best idea, but certainly the fastest

Comment: Spring 4.3.6 & Spring Boot 1.4...3? Might upgrade to 1.5.1 tmr. We're transitioning to new technologies right now and I'm in charge of figuring Spring out. Only restriction is that things must be native to spring in itself.

Comment: Can UrlBasedViewResolver be used? If so, how do I implement it?

Comment: 1.5.1 is the newest version. (around week), 1.4.3 version should have it. Try in documentation. maybe there's something specified that you missing http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

Comment: Hi, I updated my question to show my attempt at creating a view resolver. Please advise me on how to further correct my code, thanks